# Unable to iterate over std::map using a std::string as a key

Tags: c++, iterator, stdstring, stdmap

My question is almost identical to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4939204/using-an-stdstring-as-a-key-for-an-stdmap), but the solution there hasn't resolved my error.

In `main.h` I have:

```
#include <map>
#include <string>

std::map<std::string, int64_t> receive_times;
```

And in `main.cpp`:

```
std::map<std::string, int64_t>::const_iterator iter;
std::map<std::string, int64_t>::const_iterator eiter = receive_times.end();

for (iter = receive_times.begin(); iter < eiter; ++iter)
  printf("%s: %ld\n", iter->first.c_str(), iter->second);
```

However, when I try and compile I get the following error:

```
error: invalid operands to binary expression ('std::map<std::string, int64_t>::const_iterator' (aka '_Rb_tree_const_iterator<value_type>') and 'std::map<std::string, int64_t>::const_iterator'
  (aka '_Rb_tree_const_iterator<value_type>'))
  for (iter = receive_times.begin(); iter < eiter; ++iter)
                                     ~~~~ ^ ~~~~~
```

The solution in the question I linked to at the top is because there was a missing `#include <string>`, but obviously I have that included. Any hints?

Comment: You shouldn't be defining variables in header files...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Iterators are not relationally comparable, only for equality. So say `iter != eiter`.

A less noisy way to write the loop:

```
for (std::map<std::string, int64_t>::const_iterator iter = receive_times.begin(),
     end = receive_times.end(); iter != end; ++iter)
{
  // ...
}
```

(Usually best to `typedef` the map type!)

Or, in C++11:

```
for (auto it = receive_times.cbegin(), end = receive_timed.cend(); it != end; ++it)
```

Or even:

```
for (const auto & p : receive_times)
{
  // do something with p.first and p.second
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The idiomatic loop structure for container iterators is:

```
for (iter = receive_times.begin(); iter != eiter; ++iter)
```