# 32 errors for something that shouldn't be happening

Tags: visual-c++, compiler-errors

I'm compiling on VC++ 2010. The following code is for a homework assignment:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include "PaintJobEst.h"

using namespace std;

int main( void )
{
    map< string, double > data;

    double numRooms = 0, costPerGallon = 0, sqrFtWallSpace = 0;

    cout << "How many rooms wil you be painting today? " << endl;
    cin >> numRooms;

    const bool numRoomsAtLeastOne = ( numRooms >= 1 );

    if ( !numRoomsAtLeastOne )
    {
        cout << "INVALID ENTRY: Please enter a value greater than or equal to 1 for the amount of rooms you wish to paint" << endl;
        main();
    }

    cout << "What is the cost of paint per gallon? " << endl;
    cin >> costPerGallon;

    const bool costCheck = ( costPerGallon >= 10.00 );

    if ( !costCheck )
    {
        cout << "INVALID ENTRY: Please enter a value greater than or equal to 10.00 for the cost-per-gallon of paint you wish to use." << endl;
        main();
    }

    cout << "What is the square feet of wallspace per gallon of paint you wish to cover? " << endl;
    cin >> sqrFtWallSpace;

    const bool sqrFeetCheck = ( sqrFtWallSpace >= 0 );

    if ( !sqrFeetCheck )
    {
        cout << "INVALID ENTRY: Please enter a value which is NON-NEGATIVE for covering the square feet of wallspace per gallon" << endl;
        main();
    }

    data.insert( pair< string, double >( "numRooms", numRooms ) );
    data.insert( pair< string, double >( "costPerGallon", costPerGallon ) );
    data.insert( pair< string, double >( "sqrFtWallSpace", sqrFtWallSpace ) );

    Estimate( data );

    system("pause");

}
```

Yet, when I compile it, I get flooded with strange errors which are related to how the `xfunctional` file. Why this is happening, I have no idea. Am I missing an include file somewhere?

**Errors**

```
>------ Build started: Project: Project17, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  main.cpp
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xfunctional(125): error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::_Tree<_Traits> &,const std::_Tree<_Traits> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::_Tree<_Traits> &' from 'const std::string'
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xtree(1885) : see declaration of 'std::operator <'
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xfunctional(124) : while compiling class template member function 'bool std::less<_Ty>::operator ()(const _Ty &,const _Ty &) const'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=std::string
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\map(71) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::less<_Ty>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=std::string
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xtree(451) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::_Tmap_traits<_Kty,_Ty,_Pr,_Alloc,_Mfl>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Kty=std::string,
1>              _Ty=double,
1>              _Pr=std::less<std::string>,
1>              _Alloc=std::allocator<std::pair<const std::string,double>>,
1>              _Mfl=false
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xtree(520) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::_Tree_nod<_Traits>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Traits=std::_Tmap_traits<std::string,double,std::less<std::string>,std::allocator<std::pair<const std::string,double>>,false>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xtree(659) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::_Tree_val<_Traits>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Traits=std::_Tmap_traits<std::string,double,std::less<std::string>,std::allocator<std::pair<const std::string,double>>,false>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\map(81) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::_Tree<_Traits>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Traits=std::_Tmap_traits<std::string,double,std::less<std::string>,std::allocator<std::pair<const std::string,double>>,false>
1>          ]
1>          c:\users\holland\documents\code\projects\studying\chapter6\project17\project17\main.cpp(13) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::map<_Kty,_Ty>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Kty=std::string,
1>              _Ty=double
1>          ]
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xfunctional(125): error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::_Tree<_Traits> &,const std::_Tree<_Traits> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::_Tree<_Traits> &' from 'const std::string'
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xtree(1885) : see declaration of 'std::operator <'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xfunctional(125): error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::_Tree<_Traits> &,const std::_Tree<_Traits> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::_Tree<_Traits> &' from 'const std::string'
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xtree(1885) : see declaration of 'std::operator <'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xfunctional(125): error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::unique_ptr<_Ty,_Dx> &,const std::unique_ptr<_Ty2,_Dx2> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::unique_ptr<_Ty,_Dx> &' from 'const std::string'
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\memory(2582) : see declaration of 'std::operator <'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xfunctional(125): error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::unique_ptr<_Ty,_Dx> &,const std::unique_ptr<_Ty2,_Dx2> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::unique_ptr<_Ty,_Dx> &' from 'const std::string'
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\memory(2582) : see declaration of 'std::operator <'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xfunctional(125): error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::unique_ptr<_Ty,_Dx> &,const std::unique_ptr<_Ty2,_Dx2> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::unique_ptr<_Ty,_Dx> &' from 'const std::string'
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\memory(2582) : see declaration of 'std::operator <'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xfunctional(125): error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::reverse_iterator<_RanIt> &,const std::reverse_iterator<_RanIt2> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::reverse_iterator<_RanIt> &' from 'const std::string'
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xutility(1356) : see declaration of 'std::operator <'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xfunctional(125): error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::reverse_iterator<_RanIt> &,const std::reverse_iterator<_RanIt2> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::reverse_iterator<_RanIt> &' from 'const std::string'
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xutility(1356) : see declaration of 'std::operator <'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xfunctional(125): error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::reverse_iterator<_RanIt> &,const std::reverse_iterator<_RanIt2> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::reverse_iterator<_RanIt> &' from 'const std::string'
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xutility(1356) : see declaration of 'std::operator <'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xfunctional(125): error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::_Revranit<_RanIt,_Base> &,const std::_Revranit<_RanIt2,_Base2> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::_Revranit<_RanIt,_Base> &' from 'const std::string'
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xutility(1179) : see declaration of 'std::operator <'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xfunctional(125): error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::_Revranit<_RanIt,_Base> &,const std::_Revranit<_RanIt2,_Base2> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::_Revranit<_RanIt,_Base> &' from 'const std::string'
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xutility(1179) : see declaration of 'std::operator <'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xfunctional(125): error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::_Revranit<_RanIt,_Base> &,const std::_Revranit<_RanIt2,_Base2> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::_Revranit<_RanIt,_Base> &' from 'const std::string'
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xutility(1179) : see declaration of 'std::operator <'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xfunctional(125): error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2> &,const std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2> &' from 'const std::string'
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\utility(318) : see declaration of 'std::operator <'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xfunctional(125): error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2> &,const std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2> &' from 'const std::string'
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\utility(318) : see declaration of 'std::operator <'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xfunctional(125): error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2> &,const std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2> &' from 'const std::string'
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\utility(318) : see declaration of 'std::operator <'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xfunctional(125): error C2676: binary '<' : 'const std::string' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator
1>  PaintJobEst.cpp
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xfunctional(125): error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::_Tree<_Traits> &,const std::_Tree<_Traits> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::_Tree<_Traits> &' from 'const std::string'
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xtree(1885) : see declaration of 'std::operator <'
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xfunctional(124) : while compiling class template member function 'bool std::less<_Ty>::operator ()(const _Ty &,const _Ty &) const'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=std::string
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\map(71) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::less<_Ty>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=std::string
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xtree(451) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::_Tmap_traits<_Kty,_Ty,_Pr,_Alloc,_Mfl>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Kty=std::string,
1>              _Ty=double,
1>              _Pr=std::less<std::string>,
1>              _Alloc=std::allocator<std::pair<const std::string,double>>,
1>              _Mfl=false
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xtree(520) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::_Tree_nod<_Traits>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Traits=std::_Tmap_traits<std::string,double,std::less<std::string>,std::allocator<std::pair<const std::string,double>>,false>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xtree(659) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::_Tree_val<_Traits>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Traits=std::_Tmap_traits<std::string,double,std::less<std::string>,std::allocator<std::pair<const std::string,double>>,false>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\map(81) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::_Tree<_Traits>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Traits=std::_Tmap_traits<std::string,double,std::less<std::string>,std::allocator<std::pair<const std::string,double>>,false>
1>          ]
1>          c:\users\holland\documents\code\projects\studying\chapter6\project17\project17\paintjobest.cpp(9) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::map<_Kty,_Ty>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Kty=std::string,
1>              _Ty=double
1>          ]
```

Comment: Add the <string> header as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4939204/using-an-stdstring-as-a-key-for-an-stdmap

Answer (score 7):

Add `#include <string>` and the problem goes away for me on VC++ 2010.