# map of vectors - how to do it

Tags: c++, dictionary, vector, stl

I have a following code:

```
std::map<std::wstring, std::vector<Table> > my_map;
my_map[L"abc"].push_back( Table() );
```

but trying to compile it it gives a lot of errors {MSVC 2010}, which I don't understand at all.

So, one rhetorical question: why MS gives a bunch of errors which people can't understand? And second: how do I fix the second line?

Thank you.

Here are the errors for the reference:

```
2>c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xfunctional(125): error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::vector<_Ty,_Ax> &,const std::vector<_Ty,_Ax> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::vector<_Ty,_Ax> &' from 'const std::wstring'
2>          c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\vector(1502) : see declaration of 'std::operator <'
2>          c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xfunctional(124) : while compiling class template member function 'bool std::less<_Ty>::operator ()(const _Ty &,const _Ty &) const'
2>          with
2>          [
2>              _Ty=std::wstring
2>          ]
2>          c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\map(71) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::less<_Ty>' being compiled
2>          with
2>          [
2>              _Ty=std::wstring
2>          ]
2>          c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xtree(451) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::_Tmap_traits<_Kty,_Ty,_Pr,_Alloc,_Mfl>' being compiled
2>          with
2>          [
2>              _Kty=std::wstring,
2>              _Ty=std::vector<Table>,
2>              _Pr=std::less<std::wstring>,
2>              _Alloc=std::allocator<std::pair<const std::wstring,std::vector<Table>>>,
2>              _Mfl=false
2>          ]
2>          c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xtree(520) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::_Tree_nod<_Traits>' being compiled
2>          with
2>          [
2>              _Traits=std::_Tmap_traits<std::wstring,std::vector<Table>,std::less<std::wstring>,std::allocator<std::pair<const std::wstring,std::vector<Table>>>,false>
2>          ]
2>          c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xtree(659) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::_Tree_val<_Traits>' being compiled
2>          with
2>          [
2>              _Traits=std::_Tmap_traits<std::wstring,std::vector<Table>,std::less<std::wstring>,std::allocator<std::pair<const std::wstring,std::vector<Table>>>,false>
2>          ]
2>          c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\map(81) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::_Tree<_Traits>' being compiled
2>          with
2>          [
2>              _Traits=std::_Tmap_traits<std::wstring,std::vector<Table>,std::less<std::wstring>,std::allocator<std::pair<const std::wstring,std::vector<Table>>>,false>
2>          ]
2>          C:\Users\Igor\OneDrive\Documents\dbhandler_app\dbinterface\database.h(115) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::map<_Kty,_Ty>' being compiled
2>          with
2>          [
2>              _Kty=std::wstring,
2>              _Ty=std::vector<Table>
2>          ]
2>c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xfunctional(125): error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::vector<_Ty,_Ax> &,const std::vector<_Ty,_Ax> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::vector<_Ty,_Ax> &' from 'const std::wstring'
2>          c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\vector(1502) : see declaration of 'std::operator <'
2>c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xfunctional(125): error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::vector<_Ty,_Ax> &,const std::vector<_Ty,_Ax> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::vector<_Ty,_Ax> &' from 'const std::wstring'
2>          c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\vector(1502) : see declaration of 'std::operator <'
2>c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xfunctional(125): error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::_Tree<_Traits> &,const std::_Tree<_Traits> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::_Tree<_Traits> &' from 'const std::wstring'
2>          c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xtree(1885) : see declaration of 'std::operator <'
2>c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xfunctional(125): error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::_Tree<_Traits> &,const std::_Tree<_Traits> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::_Tree<_Traits> &' from 'const std::wstring'
2>          c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xtree(1885) : see declaration of 'std::operator <'
2>c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xfunctional(125): error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::_Tree<_Traits> &,const std::_Tree<_Traits> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::_Tree<_Traits> &' from 'const std::wstring'
2>          c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xtree(1885) : see declaration of 'std::operator <'
2>c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xfunctional(125): error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::unique_ptr<_Ty,_Dx> &,const std::unique_ptr<_Ty2,_Dx2> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::unique_ptr<_Ty,_Dx> &' from 'const std::wstring'
2>          c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\memory(2582) : see declaration of 'std::operator <'
2>c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xfunctional(125): error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::unique_ptr<_Ty,_Dx> &,const std::unique_ptr<_Ty2,_Dx2> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::unique_ptr<_Ty,_Dx> &' from 'const std::wstring'
2>          c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\memory(2582) : see declaration of 'std::operator <'
2>c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xfunctional(125): error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::unique_ptr<_Ty,_Dx> &,const std::unique_ptr<_Ty2,_Dx2> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::unique_ptr<_Ty,_Dx> &' from 'const std::wstring'
2>          c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\memory(2582) : see declaration of 'std::operator <'
2>c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xfunctional(125): error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::reverse_iterator<_RanIt> &,const std::reverse_iterator<_RanIt2> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::reverse_iterator<_RanIt> &' from 'const std::wstring'
2>          c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xutility(1356) : see declaration of 'std::operator <'
2>c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xfunctional(125): error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::reverse_iterator<_RanIt> &,const std::reverse_iterator<_RanIt2> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::reverse_iterator<_RanIt> &' from 'const std::wstring'
2>          c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xutility(1356) : see declaration of 'std::operator <'
2>c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xfunctional(125): error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::reverse_iterator<_RanIt> &,const std::reverse_iterator<_RanIt2> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::reverse_iterator<_RanIt> &' from 'const std::wstring'
2>          c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xutility(1356) : see declaration of 'std::operator <'
2>c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xfunctional(125): error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::_Revranit<_RanIt,_Base> &,const std::_Revranit<_RanIt2,_Base2> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::_Revranit<_RanIt,_Base> &' from 'const std::wstring'
2>          c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xutility(1179) : see declaration of 'std::operator <'
2>c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xfunctional(125): error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::_Revranit<_RanIt,_Base> &,const std::_Revranit<_RanIt2,_Base2> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::_Revranit<_RanIt,_Base> &' from 'const std::wstring'
2>          c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xutility(1179) : see declaration of 'std::operator <'
2>c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xfunctional(125): error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::_Revranit<_RanIt,_Base> &,const std::_Revranit<_RanIt2,_Base2> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::_Revranit<_RanIt,_Base> &' from 'const std::wstring'
2>          c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xutility(1179) : see declaration of 'std::operator <'
2>c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xfunctional(125): error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2> &,const std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2> &' from 'const std::wstring'
2>          c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\utility(318) : see declaration of 'std::operator <'
2>c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xfunctional(125): error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2> &,const std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2> &' from 'const std::wstring'
2>          c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\utility(318) : see declaration of 'std::operator <'
2>c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xfunctional(125): error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2> &,const std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2> &' from 'const std::wstring'
2>          c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\utility(318) : see declaration of 'std::operator <'
2>c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xfunctional(125): error C2676: binary '<' : 'const std::wstring' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator
```

Comment: Did you include `vector` and `map`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I can assure you that Microsoft's compilers aren't the only C++ compilers who will take every excuse to bury you under a massive hairball of undecipherable error messages.

Comment: If you post questions about build errors, you should know by now that you include the errors in the question.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik, but at least with gcc it is easier to decipher and fix.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, added. Sorry.

Comment: I use Visual Studio 2015 and it compiles fine.

Comment: I find it highly unlikely that every line of error messages from the compiler begins with "2>". Can you try and clean up your posted error messages. They are bad enough, as you said, coming out of your compiler, but they got messed up even more, in your post.

Comment: double check if you have `#include <string>`

Comment: @SamVarshavchik, I just copy and paste them as they appear in the IDE Build Log.

Comment: What is Table here ? Is it a template ? If yes, you want to specify typename somewhere.

Comment: is `Table` copyable?

Comment: What has this `bool std::operator <(const std::vector<...` to do with the posted code? I think that the error is generated by a different piece of code. It looks like it is trying to compare two vectors.

Comment: @ZDF, from the first error message: 2>          C:\Users\Igor\OneDrive\Documents\dbhandler_app\dbinterface\database.h(115) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::map<_Kty,_Ty>' being compiled
2>          with
2>          [
2>              _Kty=std::wstring,
2>              _Ty=std::vector<Table>
2>          ]
, so it looks like it does check the proper line. But I don't understand this message at all then.

Comment: @Thomas, no, there is no copy constructor defined.

Comment: @FlorentDUGUET, Table is not a template but the class/struct I defined.

Comment: That only partially answers the question. If it is not copyable, then you can't copy it in.

Comment: Igor, `vector of Table` is the value, not the key. Therefore, it is strange that the compiler asks for `less`. If you have included `<string>`, `<map>` and `<vector>`, there should be no problem. Define a dummy `less` for `vector of Table` and see what happens.

Comment: The map of vector is a member of Table ?

Answer (score 2):

*scratches chin* Hm. This error message looks suspicious:

> 2>c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   10.0\VC\include\xfunctional(125): error C2676: binary '<' : 'const std::wstring' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type
>   acceptable to the predefined operator

*pulls out heavy object and plops it onto the table* I see... into my crystal ball... *The hyperlink [Using an std::string as a key for an std::map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4939204/using-an-stdstring-as-a-key-for-an-stdmap) floats mysteriously into the mist*

Ah yes! That was it. You forgot to `#include <string>`.

That's what happens when you:

1. Don't produce an MCVE
2. Neglect to follow the advice of a previous commenter to "double check if you have `#include <string>`"

Comment: this is very weird. All other code that uses std::wstring compiles fine without this include. But yes - you're right. It was missing and after adding it, the code compiles.